TypeError in Tanstack Query React
I am new to react tanstack query and I am building a todo list app to reinforce the concepts that I am learning. The todos are coming from DummyJson API -https://dummyjson.com/docs/todos. The response data object has a few properties - limit, skip, total and an array of todos as defined in types/index.ts.
// types/index.ts
export type TodoType = {
    id: number;
    completed: boolean;
    todo: string;
    userId: number;
};

export type TodosType = {
    limit: number;
    skip: number;
    total: number;
    todos: TodoType[]; // Correctly defined as an array of Todo objects
};

In my lib folder, I have a react-query file.
// lib/react.query.ts
import { QueryClient, DefaultOptions } from '@tanstack/react-query';

const queryConfig: DefaultOptions = {
  queries: {
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
  },
};

export const queryClient = new QueryClient({ defaultOptions: queryConfig });

Which is being used in my api folder.
// api/getTodos.ts
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { axios } from '../lib/axios';
import { TodoType  } from '../types';

export const getTodos = (): Promise<TodoType[]> => {
  return axios.get('/todos');
}; 

export const useTodos = () => {
    return useQuery({queryKey: ['todos'], queryFn: () => getTodos()});
};

The issue is that in my TodoWrapper where I am utilising this useTodos hook, in the console.log,I get the typescript error Property 'todos' does not exist on type 'TodoType[]'.Which is strange beacuse I'm sure that todos does exist in TodoType.
export const TodoWrapper = () => {
  const todosQuery = useTodos();

  if(todosQuery.isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>

  if(!todosQuery.data) return null;

console.log(todosQuery.data.todos);

}


A field todos sure exists in the TodosType, but not in the TodoType. Notice you return TodoType[] from getTodos instead of TodosType[] (you're missing "s").

Thank you for that. I have fix the typo though, it still returns this error, Property 'todos' does not exist on type 'TodosType[]'

The axios.get('/todos') call returns an object containing a field data.
You should refactor your function to const { data } = await axios.get('/todos');, and then return the data (object of type TodosType[]).
Alternatively, access todosQuery.data.data.todos.

this doesn't work sadly :(  to be honest it think I'll just use any type and call it a day.

What's the output of calling console.log(todosQuery.data);?

It's an object with the properties: limit, skip, total and todos. With todos of course being an array of objects.

it seems to work now, just had to restart the application lol

I assume you're using VSCode. It's a common issue when working with Typescript that the TS server process starts to malfunction. Restarting it can fix the problem.
To quickly reload the VScode, do:

Show all commands (Ctrl+Shift+P on Windows, or ⌘+Shift+P on a Mac)
Select "Developer: Reload window"

